# How to make glass material LESS transparent/maintain its color?

Tags: materials, node-editor, glass

Ok, Ive tried everything but here is what I have for a glass material (the teardrop) right now:

[image]

With this setup:https://blenderartists.org/t/colored-glass-in-cycles/631184

Issue is the glass is really dark right now, even with all colors set to white. I need a LIGHT colored glass despite the darker background, so still transparent but not as "inky"

How can I get this?

Comment: Increase the roughness??

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include an image of the shader you are using as part of your post (not as a link so some other site).